# Generalizing a reference counting class for use with non-specific protected classes

Tags: reference-counting

Trying to retro-fit a non-COM class with reference count based protection that prevents its deconstruction when any of its members methods are currently in process.

Wrote a small class designed to call AddRef on construction, and Release on deconstruction; declare an instance upon entry into the protected classes member functions - works OK, but it's bound to protected class which means I can only use it with that class.

I would like to generalize it so that it can be used with any class. I was thinking maybe templates would help, but I don't know enough about them to write classes that use them.  Here's the class as it exists now, working, but limited to being used within ClsEditWndData instances

```
#ifndef _ClsProtectMe_h_
#   define _ClsProtectMe_h_
    typedef void (ClsEditWndData::*pfnREFCOUNTER)();
    class ClsProtectMe
    {
        public:
            ClsProtectMe(                               // constructor
                pfnREFCOUNTER pfnAddRef,                // pointer to callers' AddRef
                pfnREFCOUNTER pfnRelease,               // pointer to callers' Release 
                ClsEditWndData* pThis ) :               // pointer to caller
                    m_pfnAddRef( pfnAddRef ),           // init stored AddRef address
                    m_pfnRelease( pfnRelease ),         // init stored Release address
                    m_pThis( pThis )                    // init stored instance address
            {                                           // ===========================
                if( m_pThis != NULL )                   // must have non-null instance
                    if( m_pfnRelease != NULL )          // must have non-null release
                        if( m_pfnAddRef != NULL )       // must have non-null addref
                            (m_pThis->*m_pfnAddRef)();  // call the addref function
            }                                           // ===========================

            virtual ~ClsProtectMe(void)                 // destructor
            {                                           // ===========================
                if( m_pThis != NULL )                   // must have non-null instance
                    if( m_pfnRelease != NULL )          // must have non-null release
                        if( m_pfnAddRef != NULL )       // must have non-null addref
                            (m_pThis->*m_pfnRelease)(); // call the release function
            }                                           // ===========================
        private:
            pfnREFCOUNTER   m_pfnAddRef;                // stored pointer to AddRef function
            pfnREFCOUNTER   m_pfnRelease;               // stored pointer to Release function
            ClsEditWndData* m_pThis;                    // stored pointer to instance
    };
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was a lot easier than I expected.  A little research into template classes gave me the answer I was looking for.  I was able to 'templateize' the above class as follows:

```
template <class T> class ClsProtect     
{
    public:
        ClsProtect( void (T::*add)(), void (T::*release)(), T* pThis )
            : m_pfnAdd( add ), m_pfnRelease( release ), m_pThis( pThis )
        {
            if( m_pThis != NULL )
                if( m_pfnAdd != NULL )
                    if( m_pfnRelease != NULL )
                        (m_pThis->*m_pfnAdd)();
        };
        virtual ~ClsProtect(){
            if( m_pThis != NULL )
                if( m_pfnAdd != NULL )
                    if( m_pfnRelease != NULL )
                        (m_pThis->*m_pfnRelease)();
        };
    private:
        void (T::*  m_pfnAdd)();
        void (T::*  m_pfnRelease)();
        T*          m_pThis;
};
```

usage:

```
void ClsEditWndData::OnKeyDown( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM )
{
    ClsProtect<ClsEditWndData>  objProtect( 
        &ClsEditWndData::AddRef, 
        &ClsEditWndData::Release, 
        this );
    ...<whatever, don't care...>...
}
```